# hiding a footer below the main body using zindex

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to hide a footer behind the main body that will show up when the main bodyy is scrolled above the footer.
the problem I have is that when I set teh footers z-index to a negative, it hides the footer nicveley but the links are unclickable

so I have tried to raise the main content  z-index up and set the footer z-index to zero but then the footer is visable above the main content

heres some code

```css
#main {
    z-index:4;
    padding:0px 0px 450px;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
#mainBg {
    background:red;
}
footer {
    padding: 50px 0;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="mainBg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean posuere, justo eget auctor sagittis, sapien odio rutrum quam, eu feugiat sem lacus lacinia quam. Morbi malesuada porta sapien eu ornare. Pellentesque vel nibh auctor lectus malesuada porttitor. Cras et dui quam. Nunc sollicitudin mi condimentum iaculis rhoncus. Sed tristique mollis sagittis. Fusce bibendum congue augue, nec scelerisque velit egestas viverra. Phasellus a rhoncus leo. In tempor sagittis rhoncus. Ut a risus viverra, ornare lacus non, ornare nisi. Curabitur luctus mauris orci, quis condimentum lacus facilisis a. Nullam cursus, nisl id sagittis feugiat, risus ipsum consequat felis, id luctus erat felis eget velit. Pellentesque vehicula risus at nibh faucibus, in venenatis tellus aliquam. Pellentesque dolor libero, vehicula et magna efficitur, sollicitudin pharetra ipsum. Curabitur tempus et sapien eu facilisis. Phasellus ipsum diam, pellentesque sed felis non, euismod malesuada orci. Nulla rutrum eros in dignissim pretium. Donec et orci leo. Nullam quis luctus massa. Donec rhoncus lacinia cursus. Fusce sed imperdiet ligula. Maecenas fermentum sed velit eget aliquam. Nullam vel ipsum erat. Mauris ultricies feugiat metus, sed scelerisque arcu imperdiet eget. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum porta felis at pharetra maximus. Curabitur efficitur turpis non interdum finibus. Mauris ut consectetur nisl, eget condimentum sem. Integer rutrum, augue vitae faucibus rutrum, metus tellus volutpat quam, in fermentum arcu risus quis libero. Curabitur faucibus pulvinar tempus. Aenean eu ex ullamcorper, ullamcorper enim a, convallis elit. Cras id facilisis turpis. Nunc urna libero, rhoncus eget blandit id, sollicitudin vitae nibh. Nunc sed nibh faucibus, consequat nibh quis, commodo neque. Nullam porttitor est a dui bibendum, non scelerisque nulla imperdiet. Mauris ut suscipit magna. Aenean magna orci, aliquam nec fringilla ut, blandit ac augue. Aliquam aliquet, metus ut congue varius, massa erat dapibus lectus, sit amet blandit libero tortor eget nibh. Nam tincidunt tristique elementum. Vivamus sagittis nec tellus ut sollicitudin. Vivamus nec lobortis nisl. Proin placerat, orci sed interdum efficitur, libero enim tempor nisl, quis iaculis nisl ligula non dolor. Mauris in felis at justo varius posuere. Nam ac lorem ex. Aliquam convallis ac metus ac condimentum. Aliquam ac ex a lacus placerat rutrum sed a eros. Nunc et tellus at enim rutrum volutpat. Praesent egestas ligula at diam convallis, eget posuere diam vulputate. Cras tempus non nibh eu hendrerit. Aenean erat odio, posuere mattis neque nec, gravida tristique velit. Aenean condimentum massa sed dictum viverra. Sed bibendum velit ac felis rhoncus volutpat feugiat ut tellus. Praesent mollis malesuada sapien vel feugiat. Vivamus scelerisque, lacus nec blandit sodales, nibh velit volutpat augue, quis vehicula urna justo ac felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed non purus eget erat vulputate varius ac vel urna. Phasellus ac tempor mauris. Morbi ut ligula tristique, fringilla metus quis, pharetra mauris. Nunc non fringilla dui, non varius sem. Quisque ullamcorper, est vitae rhoncus porttitor, sapien urna semper orci, non aliquam lacus ipsum non sem. Phasellus volutpat nibh nulla, eu auctor lacus suscipit eget.</div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <a href="http://google.co.uk">Google link</a>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </footer>
</body>
```

I have added a couple of links to js fiddles to show this in action

[JSFIDDLE - negative z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/w4Lw527z/1/)

[JSFIDDLE - positive zindex](http://jsfiddle.net/w4Lw527z/2/)

Comment: If the footer will only show up once the main body scrolls past...why position the footer at all? Alternatively, any JS scrolling plug-in will take care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `main`, and then add either `padding` to the bottom of body or `height`.  You are still under `main` which is causing this (as stated in comments).

Padding Bottom Solution:

```css
#main {
    z-index:4;
    padding:0px 0px 450px;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

#mainBg {
    background:red;
    
}

footer {
    padding: 50px 0;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    width:100%;
}

body {
  padding-bottom:200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="mainBg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean posuere, justo eget auctor sagittis, sapien odio rutrum quam, eu feugiat sem lacus lacinia quam. Morbi malesuada porta sapien eu ornare. Pellentesque vel nibh auctor lectus malesuada porttitor. Cras et dui quam. Nunc sollicitudin mi condimentum iaculis rhoncus. Sed tristique mollis sagittis. Fusce bibendum congue augue, nec scelerisque velit egestas viverra. Phasellus a rhoncus leo. In tempor sagittis rhoncus. Ut a risus viverra, ornare lacus non, ornare nisi. Curabitur luctus mauris orci, quis condimentum lacus facilisis a. Nullam cursus, nisl id sagittis feugiat, risus ipsum consequat felis, id luctus erat felis eget velit. Pellentesque vehicula risus at nibh faucibus, in venenatis tellus aliquam. Pellentesque dolor libero, vehicula et magna efficitur, sollicitudin pharetra ipsum. Curabitur tempus et sapien eu facilisis. Phasellus ipsum diam, pellentesque sed felis non, euismod malesuada orci. Nulla rutrum eros in dignissim pretium. Donec et orci leo. Nullam quis luctus massa. Donec rhoncus lacinia cursus. Fusce sed imperdiet ligula. Maecenas fermentum sed velit eget aliquam. Nullam vel ipsum erat. Mauris ultricies feugiat metus, sed scelerisque arcu imperdiet eget. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum porta felis at pharetra maximus. Curabitur efficitur turpis non interdum finibus. Mauris ut consectetur nisl, eget condimentum sem. Integer rutrum, augue vitae faucibus rutrum, metus tellus volutpat quam, in fermentum arcu risus quis libero. Curabitur faucibus pulvinar tempus. Aenean eu ex ullamcorper, ullamcorper enim a, convallis elit. Cras id facilisis turpis. Nunc urna libero, rhoncus eget blandit id, sollicitudin vitae nibh. Nunc sed nibh faucibus, consequat nibh quis, commodo neque. Nullam porttitor est a dui bibendum, non scelerisque nulla imperdiet. Mauris ut suscipit magna. Aenean magna orci, aliquam nec fringilla ut, blandit ac augue. Aliquam aliquet, metus ut congue varius, massa erat dapibus lectus, sit amet blandit libero tortor eget nibh. Nam tincidunt tristique elementum. Vivamus sagittis nec tellus ut sollicitudin. Vivamus nec lobortis nisl. Proin placerat, orci sed interdum efficitur, libero enim tempor nisl, quis iaculis nisl ligula non dolor. Mauris in felis at justo varius posuere. Nam ac lorem ex. Aliquam convallis ac metus ac condimentum. Aliquam ac ex a lacus placerat rutrum sed a eros. Nunc et tellus at enim rutrum volutpat. Praesent egestas ligula at diam convallis, eget posuere diam vulputate. Cras tempus non nibh eu hendrerit. Aenean erat odio, posuere mattis neque nec, gravida tristique velit. Aenean condimentum massa sed dictum viverra. Sed bibendum velit ac felis rhoncus volutpat feugiat ut tellus. Praesent mollis malesuada sapien vel feugiat. Vivamus scelerisque, lacus nec blandit sodales, nibh velit volutpat augue, quis vehicula urna justo ac felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed non purus eget erat vulputate varius ac vel urna. Phasellus ac tempor mauris. Morbi ut ligula tristique, fringilla metus quis, pharetra mauris. Nunc non fringilla dui, non varius sem. Quisque ullamcorper, est vitae rhoncus porttitor, sapien urna semper orci, non aliquam lacus ipsum non sem. Phasellus volutpat nibh nulla, eu auctor lacus suscipit eget.</div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <a href="http://google.co.uk">Google link</a>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Height Solution:

```css
#main {
    z-index:4;
    padding:0px 0px 450px;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

#mainBg {
    background:red;
    
}

footer {
    padding: 50px 0;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    width:100%;
}

body {
  height:1500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="mainBg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean posuere, justo eget auctor sagittis, sapien odio rutrum quam, eu feugiat sem lacus lacinia quam. Morbi malesuada porta sapien eu ornare. Pellentesque vel nibh auctor lectus malesuada porttitor. Cras et dui quam. Nunc sollicitudin mi condimentum iaculis rhoncus. Sed tristique mollis sagittis. Fusce bibendum congue augue, nec scelerisque velit egestas viverra. Phasellus a rhoncus leo. In tempor sagittis rhoncus. Ut a risus viverra, ornare lacus non, ornare nisi. Curabitur luctus mauris orci, quis condimentum lacus facilisis a. Nullam cursus, nisl id sagittis feugiat, risus ipsum consequat felis, id luctus erat felis eget velit. Pellentesque vehicula risus at nibh faucibus, in venenatis tellus aliquam. Pellentesque dolor libero, vehicula et magna efficitur, sollicitudin pharetra ipsum. Curabitur tempus et sapien eu facilisis. Phasellus ipsum diam, pellentesque sed felis non, euismod malesuada orci. Nulla rutrum eros in dignissim pretium. Donec et orci leo. Nullam quis luctus massa. Donec rhoncus lacinia cursus. Fusce sed imperdiet ligula. Maecenas fermentum sed velit eget aliquam. Nullam vel ipsum erat. Mauris ultricies feugiat metus, sed scelerisque arcu imperdiet eget. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum porta felis at pharetra maximus. Curabitur efficitur turpis non interdum finibus. Mauris ut consectetur nisl, eget condimentum sem. Integer rutrum, augue vitae faucibus rutrum, metus tellus volutpat quam, in fermentum arcu risus quis libero. Curabitur faucibus pulvinar tempus. Aenean eu ex ullamcorper, ullamcorper enim a, convallis elit. Cras id facilisis turpis. Nunc urna libero, rhoncus eget blandit id, sollicitudin vitae nibh. Nunc sed nibh faucibus, consequat nibh quis, commodo neque. Nullam porttitor est a dui bibendum, non scelerisque nulla imperdiet. Mauris ut suscipit magna. Aenean magna orci, aliquam nec fringilla ut, blandit ac augue. Aliquam aliquet, metus ut congue varius, massa erat dapibus lectus, sit amet blandit libero tortor eget nibh. Nam tincidunt tristique elementum. Vivamus sagittis nec tellus ut sollicitudin. Vivamus nec lobortis nisl. Proin placerat, orci sed interdum efficitur, libero enim tempor nisl, quis iaculis nisl ligula non dolor. Mauris in felis at justo varius posuere. Nam ac lorem ex. Aliquam convallis ac metus ac condimentum. Aliquam ac ex a lacus placerat rutrum sed a eros. Nunc et tellus at enim rutrum volutpat. Praesent egestas ligula at diam convallis, eget posuere diam vulputate. Cras tempus non nibh eu hendrerit. Aenean erat odio, posuere mattis neque nec, gravida tristique velit. Aenean condimentum massa sed dictum viverra. Sed bibendum velit ac felis rhoncus volutpat feugiat ut tellus. Praesent mollis malesuada sapien vel feugiat. Vivamus scelerisque, lacus nec blandit sodales, nibh velit volutpat augue, quis vehicula urna justo ac felis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed non purus eget erat vulputate varius ac vel urna. Phasellus ac tempor mauris. Morbi ut ligula tristique, fringilla metus quis, pharetra mauris. Nunc non fringilla dui, non varius sem. Quisque ullamcorper, est vitae rhoncus porttitor, sapien urna semper orci, non aliquam lacus ipsum non sem. Phasellus volutpat nibh nulla, eu auctor lacus suscipit eget.</div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <a href="http://google.co.uk">Google link</a>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>footer footer
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Links are still not clickable.

Comment: The problem isn't that the links are unclickable.  It is that you are still under the `main` div.  You have padding bottom which means the content goes `450px`.

Comment: @Paulie_D see my edit, after I add a height to `body`

Comment: actually this works great if I add a new div inside the main div and set that position to relative, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your #main includes 450px padding botton so it is just over the footer.
Try to add 450px padding bottom to the body and remove it from #main.